# Can Visual Studio be set to automatically make file writable when I go to edit it?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I have been using TFS with Visual Studio 2017 and we recently switched the source control to git. I successfully made some changes and committed them to the master branch. Then I made a new branch (just trying things out) and every time I go to edit a different file, it asks "You are trying to edit read-only files. Do you want to mark these files as writable?" Is there a way to disable this popup so it automatically makes it writable? Also, if I edit a file that when saving updates another file (like editing a dbml which will change the designer.cs file), this "cascading" change is not working unless I manually make the file writable.

Comment: Git don't use or set/unset the read-only flag (like TFVC is doing it). So, open the file explorer, and unset the flag on all files. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @Phillippe Interesting there prob isn't a built-in way but maybe my problem is increased because we just switched over from TFS, so I have all these projects with read-only files to start with. And git wouldn't have made them read-only. I guess I just have to do it (make them writable) once.

Comment: Discovered Visual Studio 2019 will ask you if you want to make them writable.